# Set certain filter field

Tags: python, django, filter

I have one innormal idea to get object through function and set to it certain field for filtering
It will look as follows

```
get_course(name='math')
# or
get_course(id=12)
# and so on
```

```
def get_course(**kwargs):
    for key, val in kwargs:
        return Course.objects.get(key=val)
```

I've tried:

```
key = 'id'
val = 1
Course.objects.filter(key=val)
```

And result was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\lyf20\Documents\Student\OpenUniProject\OpenUni\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lyf20\Documents\Student\OpenUniProject\OpenUni\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lyf20\Documents\Student\OpenUniProject\OpenUni\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\lyf20\Documents\Student\OpenUniProject\OpenUni\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\lyf20\Documents\Student\OpenUniProject\OpenUni\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1318, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
  File "C:\Users\lyf20\Documents\Student\OpenUniProject\OpenUni\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1190, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "C:\Users\lyf20\Documents\Student\OpenUniProject\OpenUni\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1049, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "C:\Users\lyf20\Documents\Student\OpenUniProject\OpenUni\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1420, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'key' into field. Choices are: complexity, course, created, description, id, image, image_courses_and_course, image_dash, is_active, is_certificated, is_video, modules, name, question, queue_number, quiz, selected_courses, short_description, tagged_items, tags, total_ended, total_started, total_watches, updated, users_ended, users_likes, users_started, video_link
```

So is it possible to make this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass variable keyword parameters to functions in python you can use dictionary unpacking

This

```
foo(**{'bar': 'baz'})
```

Is equivalent to

```
foo(bar='baz')
```

You could probably do something like this

```
def get_course(**kwargs):
    return Course.objects.get(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this code and if so, what's the issue you're running into? This looks fine to me.

Comment: it results:  
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'key' into field. Choices are: complexity, course, created,

Comment: @DamirNafikov it looks like the error message got cut off - could you post the remaining lines of the error message?